# Is there a way to float a div leftwards and upwards, disregarding siblings height?

Tags: html, grid

I have four divs, they each have a width of 50%; float:left, and different heights.
The problem is that there are two divs per 'line' , but the next set doesn't start until both 2 divs have ended. (I.e. Div2 is much taller than div1, but div3 doesn't meet div1, it starts at the bottom of div2)

```
 DIV1 DIV2
      DIV2
      DIV2
 DIV3 DIV4
 DIV3 DIV4
```

Is there a way to get them to float up as well as left, like this: ?

```
DIV1 DIV2
DIV3 DIV2
DIV3 DIV2
DIV4
DIV4
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a container to the right hand side column and the left hand side column.
EG: `<div class="rhs-container"></div>` and `<div class="lhs-container">`

Example Here:
http://jsfiddle.net/W5FTP/